# Enforcing that a user should have one or more email addresses

Tags: database-design, constraint, relations

I'm trying to design an application where a user can authenticate oneself with **one password** and **one or more email addresses**. I'm not sure how to enforce this constraint.

The tables so far are simple:

Table `users`:

```
id | password |
--------------------------------------
```

Table `email_addresses`:

```
user | email |
--------------------------------------
```

However, in the current situation, a user can also have zero email addresses, thereby preventing the user from authenticating oneself.

What's the best way to deal with this type of constraint?

Answer (score 2):

Add a column to the `users` table; `email_primary`.  Prevent the new column from accepting NULL values.

When you want to authenticate a user, simply use a `UNION` query, similar to:

```
SELECT id, email_primary
FROM users
UNION ALL
SELECT user, email
FROM email_addresses;
```

Comment: It is not possible to add a foreign key constraint between `users.email_primary` and `email_addresses.email` because there is already a foreign key constraint between `email_addresses.user` and `users.id`, right? The chicken-egg problem would occur. Is that why a `UNION` query should be used? Therefore, it would be possible that an email address would be present in the `users` table, but not in the `email_addresses` table, correct?

Comment: The vast majority of users will only have a single email address, which would be stored in the `users` table.  Only if they had more than one email address would they need rows in `email_addresses`. Is that what you are wondering?